# Why is Selection.Find not returning all results in Word VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to extract text out of a document based on certain formatting rules, e.g. the font size equals 10.5. This is what I'm doing now:

```
Selection.Find.Font.Size = 10.5
Text = ""

Do While Selection.Find.Execute = True
    Text = Text + Selection
Loop

Debug.Print Text
```

It works, but for some reason it doesn't seems to return all results. When I do a manual search, i.e. Ctrl+H, and use the same formatting rule many more results are returned.

What could cause this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It isn't necessary to prefix your questions with the programming language -- we can infer that from the tags or the body text. If you must include it, [please work it into the question title organically](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61055/147645). Thanks.

Comment: Ok, thanks, will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

In VBA `+` is not used for concatenation. You have to replace it with `&`

Change `Text = Text + Selection` to `Text = Text & Selection` and try again. I have tested it and it works...

Comment: Sid, you're always right! But why does this work? `Dim s As String: s = "a" + "b": MsgBox s` - The result is `"ab"`!

Comment: Yes it works in this case because "a" and "b" are "Strings". In the actual code only `Text` is a string and `Selection` isn't. If you change the code to `Text = Text + Selection.Range.Text` then it will work. Having said that, "+" should always be avoided for concatenation.

Comment: I do always use `&` myself, but I don't know that I agree/it is completely correct to say "*`+` is not used for concatenation.*"

Comment: Check the Excel help for `+ Operator`. From Excel's Inbuilt help `When you use the + operator, you may not be able to determine whether addition or string concatenation will occur. Use the & operator for concatenation to eliminate ambiguity and provide self-documenting code.`