# Outlook VBA changes message font size

Tags: vba, outlook

I have code which alters the sensitivity of a message. It does work but the font size changes. Is something wrong with the code?

```
Public Sub MakeThisConfidential()
    Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Sensitivity = olConfidential
    Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem.Save
    Set MsgSub = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Set objMail = Outlook.Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Subject = MsgSub.Subject
    MsgSub.Subject = Subject & " - [CONFIDENTIAL]"
    email = objMail.Body
    info = vbNewLine & "AUTO TEXT: This message has been marked as 'CONFIDENTIAL' please treat it as such"
    objMail.Body = email & info
End Sub
```

Comment: What format is the message in (plain/RTF/HTML)?

Comment: Thanks JP. But I have a further question. For some reason when the script runs the email font size changes. Would this be because of the script?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I'll delete the comment and repost as answer.

Comment: That's what [Tim](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350066/outlook-vba-script-changes-message-font-size/11352082#comment14948072_11350066) was getting at. If you use `.Body` and the message is HTML, it will reformat the message body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to use the `.HTMLBody` property instead of `.Body`.

Also, the concatenation character in VBA is `&`, [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318016/why-is-selection-find-not-returning-all-results-in-word-vba/11318477#comment14901092_11318477) `+`.

If using `.Body` you will need to use `vbNewLine` to create a line break. If using `.HTMLBody` you will need to use HTML/CSS syntax such as `<p></p>` to create space.

Comment: + 1 Yup retested it with plain text and HTML and it works fine :)

Comment: Thanks! After using 'objMail.HTMLBody' it stopped the problem of altering the message text

Comment: @user1504833 glad to hear it!

Comment: The code is now.
info = " <html> <body> <FONT color=#666666> <p></p> AUTO TEXT: This message has been marked as 'CONFIDENTIAL' please treat it as such </body> </font> </html>"